# Building a time slider, not sure where to start

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to create a time display similar to the image below.

I would like to create it dynamically without having to use an image, but I am falling short on the best way to do it.

Basically I want 100 points that will be resposive inside a div, so point 1 will start at 0% and point 100 will end at 100%.

I can figure out how to get the points at each multiple of 5 to vary in height.

For now I am just seeking a little guidance on where to start looking. I thought of using an SVG but I am not too well versed in it and I would like some input before spending hours trying to hammer in that solution.

In the next step I will need to change the color of a specefic point based on a slider below it (so if the slider is dragged to 70% width I need to target node 70 and chage its color)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout the jQuery UI slider (https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps) to get you started. Likely you want to use the example that snaps to increments, then from there you can add css styles to make the slider look how you want it.

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 1,
      max: 100,
      step: 5,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: Ha! I was actually just on that, it is the css, or getting the lines up at each point, that I was puzzling on - but i like the way you think